# Post JSON data to Microsoft Graph API Azure Function

Tags: c#, post, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, azure-functions

I'm trying to use an Azure function to forward an Outlook email using its ID.

```
var url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('<blah>')/messages/" + ID + "/forward";
var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, content);
log.Info(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
```

The result I'm getting is `The value of the parameter 'ToRecipients' is empty. Specify 'ToRecipients' either in the message object or in the action.`

The data variable I'm passing in is `{"message":{"ToRecipients":[{"emailAddress":{"address":"<blah>"}}]}}`.

What am I doing wrong? How do I successfully post a data JSON object? I feel like I've tried every example I can find online and I haven't had any luck.

FYI, token has already been attached to headers, I'm just not showing that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be double serializing the data to be sent.

First when you manually serialize

```
...JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data)...
```

and second when you call `PostAsJsonAsync`

```
client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, content);
```

which would serialize the provided object to JSON before posting.

If calling `PostAsJsonAsync` then no need for you to create the content manually

```
//...

var url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('<blah>')/messages/" + ID + "/forward";
var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, data);
var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
log.Info(result);

//...
```